# Eval in anchor href

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code behind:

```
protected string VcdControlPanelLink { get; set; }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    VcdControlPanelLink = "http://www.mywebsite.com";
}
```

And the following markup:

```
<a href='<%# Eval(VcdControlPanelLink) %>' target="_blank" title="View the VDC control panel">VDC control panel</a>
```

But when I run the page, the href tag is rendered as an empty string:

```
<a title="View the VDC control panel" target="_blank" href="">VDC control panel</a>
```

I have tried various combinations of markup etc, but cannot get it to work. What am i missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use [data binding expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) `<%# ... %>` in templates (e.g. the `ItemTemplate` of a GridView), data binding is invoked automatically. However, if you use such expressions outside of templates, you need to invoke data binding yourself by calling `Control.DataBind()` (or `this.DataBind()` in your case):

```
protected string VcdControlPanelLink { get; set; }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    VcdControlPanelLink = "http://www.mywebsite.com";
    this.DataBind();
}

<!-- Note that you do *not* use Eval here! -->
<a href='<%# VcdControlPanelLink %>' target="_blank" ... />
```

---

However, I don't think data binding is the right tool here. Since you are using basic HTML elements (instead of web controls), you can just use an inline ASP.NET expression (no `this.DataBind()` required):

```
<a href='<%= VcdControlPanelLink %>' target="_blank" ... />
```

---

In any case, make sure your link does not contain quotes `'`, or you are in for some HTML injection. If the value is supplied by the user, don't forget to [HtmlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmlencode.aspx) and sanitize it.

Comment: Spot on! Thanks. I thought i had tried that, but think I used <%# instead of <%=

Comment: @ChrisO: Glad I could help! For completeness, I also added an example that uses data binding `<%# ... %>` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Make your property public and access it like this,

```
public string VcdControlPanelLink { get; set; }

<a href='<%= VcdControlPanelLink %>' target="_blank" title="View the VDC control panel">VDC control panel</a>
```

Comment: Should that really be `%%` in there? If so what does that mean - I've not come across it before...